# angular guard not redirecting to the url specified. Instead shows blank screen

Tags: routes, angular-ui-router

```
@Injectable()
export class AdminGuard implements CanActivate {

  constructor(

    public ftSubmitResponse: ResponseService,
    private router: Router) { }

  canActivate() {
    if (this.ftSubmitResponse.isenggAccount) {
      return true;

  }
  return false;
  }
}
```

the way i am using gaurd in route.guard file is-

```
   path: 'retail',  children: [

  { path: 'custom', component: engComponent, canActivate: [AdminGuard] }]
```

i don't know what i am doing wrong over. is there any other way to implement the guard. If isenggAccount is logged in and he refreshed on the page where gaurd is present, it gives out blank screen.

Answer (score 0):

https://angular.io/api/router/CanActivate

```
canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot)
```

You need the route and state snapshots so Angular can have context for your guard.

Comment: Set "ftSubmitResponse.isenggAccount" to true for the time being. If it still doesn't work, then show me your entire guard code.

Comment: With your imports and with the snapshots present. You need those. Did you set the flag to true?

Comment: Cant help you if you don't show me more of your code. I know for sure your guard isnt the problem here.